# Probability of an "event" $E=\{X_s=X_t\text{ for some }s\neq t\}$ for $\{X_r\}_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$ with i.i.d. uniform distribution on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I got this problem from my friend:

Given a complete probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Assume $\{X_r|r\in\mathbb{R}\}$ are i.i.d. with the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. What is the probability of the "event" $E=\{X_s=X_t\text{ for some }s\neq t\}$?

My first thought is that this may not be an event. So basically here are two parts of the question:

(1) Is this actually an event? That is, is this set measurable in this probability space? If not, what is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing it?

(2) Does this set contains a subset $E'$, which is measurable and with probability 1? That is, is there any $E'\subset E$ such that $E\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}(E')=1$?